# Linker error building fibonnacci example with boost::coroutine2 with Boost 1.60 using Dynamic Linking

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2015, boost-coroutine2

I have made a simple project in visual studio 2015 to reproduce an issue I'm having in a larger codebase with Boost 1.60

I have tried to simply compile and run a sample found here: https://github.com/boostorg/coroutine2/blob/develop/example/fibonacci.cpp
with 1 slight change - to use dynamic libraries.

Thus, my full code is as follows:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

#define BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK //This is the only difference

#include <boost/coroutine2/all.hpp>

int main() {
    boost::coroutines2::coroutine< int >::pull_type source(
        [](boost::coroutines2::coroutine< int >::push_type & sink) {
        int first = 1, second = 1;
        sink(first);
        sink(second);
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
            int third = first + second;
            first = second;
            second = third;
            sink(third);
        }
    });
    for (auto i : source) {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\nDone" << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

However, I am getting a linker error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: coroutine2-test, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Source.cpp
1>c:\users\lynden\boost_1_60_0\boost\context\execution_context.ipp(209): warning C4251: 'boost::context::execution_context::ptr_': class 'boost::intrusive_ptr<boost::context::detail::activation_record>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'boost::context::execution_context'
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class boost::intrusive_ptr<struct boost::context::detail::activation_record> boost::context::detail::activation_record::current_rec" (?current_rec@activation_record@detail@context@boost@@2V?$intrusive_ptr@Uactivation_record@detail@context@boost@@@4@A)
1>D:\random projects\coroutine2-test\Debug\coroutine2-test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I have of course set the include directory to my boost directory and my linker additional directory to the boost/stage/lib directory.

Comment: coroutine2 is different to coroutine, but you have made me realise I don't have a boost_coroutine2-vc140-mt-gd-1_60.lib or .dll - I wonder if that's necessary or if it's header-only?
My understanding of the way boost links to its libraries is that it uses some VS hax to automatically link them, without needing the `-lboost_coroutine2` part.

Comment: I am able to build this example with static linking, however for my larger code base we are using dynamic linking, so I think I still need this to work properly with dynamic linking

Answer (score 0):

You need to link against boost.context (used by boost.coroutine2).
Tell the compiler/linker where it can find the shared library of boost.context too.

Comment: I am indeed linking to the shared libraries:
... link.exe /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /OUT:"D:\random projects\coroutine2-test\Debug\coroutine2-test.exe" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Lynden\boost_1_60_0\stage\lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib **"boost_coroutine-vc140-mt-gd-1_60.lib" "boost_context-vc140-mt-gd-1_60.lib" "boost_system-vc140-mt-gd-1_60.lib"** ... etc

Answer (score -1):

You need to compile Boost using standard C++14 (option "-std=c++14"), otherwise Boost.Context will not provide the necessary implementation to support Boost.Coroutine2 and the compiler will fail to link.

Comment: Does visual studio provide such an option?

Comment: VS Studio doesn't fully support C++14 Features, according to their website. [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx#cpp14table)
I don't know if it is possible to compile Boost with full C++14 support.
You should check the Boost documentation about building it for VS [link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#get-boost)
If it is as similar as building boost for linux, you will probably have to add to CXXFLAGS the option "-std=c++14" (I don't know if msvc supports that option).